# Jackson: Serialize only 10 Properties out of 100

Tags: jackson

Jackson by default includes all public getters. But if I have hundreds of getters and I want to serialize just few of them, how can I achieve this?

I don't want to use `@JsonIgnore` annotation to specify all others hundred properties.

Comment: What is the selection criteria for the serialized properties?

Comment: just few random fields I want to show

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson's [views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) or [filters](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) to select the serialization form of your object. Here is an example using the filter which picks up the properties with the given names:

```
public class JacksonFilter {

    @JsonFilter("filter")
    public static class Bean {
        private final String field1;
        private final String field12;
        private final String field10;
        private final String field100;

        public Bean(String field1, String field12, String field10, String field100) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field12 = field12;
            this.field10 = field10;
            this.field100 = field100;
        }

        public String getField1() {
            return field1;
        }

        public String getField12() {
            return field12;
        }

        public String getField10() {
            return field10;
        }

        public String getField100() {
            return field100;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        filters.addFilter("filter",
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("field12", "field100"));
        mapper.setFilters(filters);
        Bean bean = new Bean("A", "B", "C", "D");
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(bean));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "field1" : "A",
  "field10" : "C"
}
```